# Of course vs Of course not?

Tags: difference

Example:

## Q1: Don't you like cats?

- A1.1: Of course.
- A1.2: Of course not.

For A1.1 and A1.2, which expresses I like cats?

## Q2: Do you dislike cats?

- A2.1: Of course.
- A2.2: of course not.

For A2.1 and A2.2, which expresses I like cats?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Q1: Don't you like cats?

A1: Of course I like.

Q2: Do you dislike cats?

A2: Of course not.

[disjunctive question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative#Question_types)

Comment: I disagree with your A1 - English speakers will use the verb "to do" rather than repeating the verb from the question.  "Q1: Don't you like cats?"  "A1: Of course I **do**."

Comment: @CanadianYankee - Or, "Of course I like cats!"

Comment: @J.R. Yes, you're right. I suppose that the problem with "Of course I like," is that the transitive verb **like** has lost its object.

Comment: @CanadianYankee - Of course I like your explanation...

Comment: @CanadianYankee, Our Native English teacher always asks us "You don't have ( a copy of the paper), do you?". If we really don't have, we always say "yes". In Chinese, it means, "yes, you're right.". It always confuse our teacher.